# How to replace list items in order of another list in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

Let's take this list:

```py
list2 = ['<@25032923629058>', 'dad', 'awd', '<@65432156029058>', '<@98450239029058>']
```

I would like to replace the elements that start with <@ in order of this list:

```py
list = ['dd#1111', 'dd#2222', 'dd#333']
```

Expected result:

```py
['dd#1111', 'dad', 'awd', 'dd#2222', 'dd#333']
```

The following script changes every item that starts with <@ with the same value, which i want to avoid:

```py
for i in range(len(list2)):
    if list2[i].startswith("<@"):
        list2[i] = list[0]
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix, delete list[0] after replacing it.

```
for i in range(len(list2)):
    if list2[i].startswith("<@"):
        list2[i] = list[0]
        del list[0]
print(list2)
```

On a second note, don't name your lists as `list`. This is a bad practice that will hurt you in the long run.

Comment: No problem! Mark this answer as correct if you can :)

Comment: I will do this, it just says I have to wait 10 minutes... :C

Answer (score 0):

you could use counter to in order to replace your words in `list2` with different words from `list` each time

I would also suggest not using the name `list` for your list since it has spacial meaning in python

This should do the trick :

```
list2 = ['<@25032923629058>', 'dad', 'awd', '<@65432156029058>', '<@98450239029058>']
list = ['dd#1111', 'dd#2222', 'dd#333']
count=0
for i in range(len(list2)):
    if list2[i].startswith("<@"):
        list2[i] = list[count]
        count+=1
print(list2)
```

output:

```
['dd#1111', 'dad', 'awd', 'dd#2222', 'dd#333']
```